# Xcode delete subword/word forward/backword eating empty space

Tags: macos, keyboard, xcode

This is really weird behaviour. Any editor I use treats empty space as a word and does not skip it. By empty space I mean newlines, tabs, spaces, etc.

Now what was for me always just a press of one shortcut option/backspace or option/Fn/backspace is complex operation, because I want to delete *just* space or newline forward and it deletes also the next word there.

Example:

```
adadada
dada
d
adadad  ad
```

When I place the cursor, (in text wrangler editor, but also other editors such as android studio etc, for example) every other then Xcode actually, so when I place it at end of first line and press fn/option/backspace , then remove just new line and I press it again and then the next word is deleted. But in Xcode it remove new line with the word on the first go.

How can I tune Xcode to behave like normal source code text editor ? (yeah little confused here)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly given the two lines

```
abc^
xyz
```

with the cursor as the ^.
You would like to know how to delete forward to achieve the following with one shortcut

```
abc^xyz
```

Again the ^ here symbolizes the text cursor.

The forward delete in xcode is mapped to both the forward delete key ("del" absent on most mac keyboards) but "fn delete" is a forward delete, "control d" also functions as delete forward. 
This can be changed in the xcode preferences -> keymap

[image]

Now to the aspect of deleting white space and newline... This is harder, it seems like xcodes subword (which selects or deletes to a capitalized section in a word), word, and expression deletes do not include whitespace.

To select just white space and newline and delete it you can do the following three commands
option shift ->, option shift <-, delete
I have an app called [betterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) that allows me to map those three commands to one single one. 
Not my softwware but been using it for years. It's amazing.

[image]